# Distribute windows virtual machine images

Tags: testing, virtual-machine, virtualbox

We use some virtual machines at work for testing. For example, if someone reports some weird bug that only happens on a specific OS we can just fire up the machine and debug it. Problem is that we may be outsourcing part of our testing workflow and we were discussing if it is legal or not to have Windows VM images available for third party download.

I would think that if we just set them and then remove the Key it is fine, but I cannot find somewhere were this is written explicitly. Has anybody had any problem like this before?